Failed to process records in ADF PIPELINE
I’m facing an issue with my ADF pipeline. It processes payment receipts (600-700 lines in a file), but some records (30-40) occasionally fail without any errors or warnings, even though the pipeline completes successfully. When I process those failed records separately, they interface with Oracle without issues. I am finding it difficult to find the root cause. Any insights or advice on debugging and fixing this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
I have tried reprocessing missing invoices one by one and it is getting processed.

can you provide your pipeline flow? output and expected output? any errors/blockers?

I am not getting any error BTW.
Thanks

You can try the below steps to avoid the above issue.

Compare your failed records and copied records and check whether there is any pattern or any specific set of values common in those and handle those. You can get the failed records using Fault tolerance in the copy activity settings. This will store the failed records in the given location where you can check for any common pattern.


Set the degree of parallelism to 1 and make sure you run your copy activity in a sequential flow. And also, check the Data consistency verification checkmark. This will check the row count of the source and target tables.


Also, reset the Integration run time and try with new Azure integration run time if issue persists with default Auto resolve integration run time.

Set the Retry to 2 or 3 in the copy activity. This will re-run the copy activity to copy all records.



You can go through this documentation to know more about these.
